# FirebaseAnimatedList display else condition data more then one

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am using FirebaseAnimatedList to get data from real-time database firebase and i want to check that if user id is present in database then it display id exist but when it's not then it display id not exist. I have three child node in the database. When FirebaseAnimatedList run and id not exist it diplay that id not exist base on number of child nodes present in databse in my case three times. If id exist in one node then it display id exist but for other two nodes it also display id not exist.

**I want that if id exist in any one or two nodes then it display id exist based on how many nodes contain uid** (if two nodes contain id it display two times) **for other nodes it does not show any thing if not exist. But if id does not exist any node then it display id not exist only one time.**

```
import 'package:bidding/global/global_variable.dart';
import 'package:bidding/screen/productDetail/product_detail.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/ui/firebase_animated_list.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyAnimatedList extends StatefulWidget {
  final DatabaseReference dbRef;
  final String category;
  const MyAnimatedList(
      {super.key, required this.dbRef, required this.category});

  @override
  State<MyAnimatedList> createState() => _MyAnimatedListState();
}

class _MyAnimatedListState extends State<MyAnimatedList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 200,
      child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          query: widget.dbRef,
          itemBuilder: (context, snapshot, animation, index) {
            final userId = snapshot.child('userid').value.toString();
            Map dbDetail = snapshot.value as Map;
            dbDetail[Key] = snapshot.key;
            if (userId == uid) {
              return Text("Your id exist");
            } else {
              return Text(
                "Your id does not exist",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  color: cRed,
                ),
              );
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

*This is my database image with three child node and that child node contain userid*

[image: This is my database image]

*This is my output image when id does not exist in every child node*

[image: This is my output image when id does not exist in every child node]

*This is my output image when uid exist in only one child node*

[image: This is my output image when uid exist in only one child node]

Is there is a way that i can fix my output using FirebaseAnimatedList.

Comment: There's no way to do this with `FirebaseAnimatedList` as far as I can tell, as its `itemBuilder` gets called with one child node at a time - so there's no way for you to check across all child nodes in there. You'll have to create your own widget to do this.

Comment: Thank You finally fix my problem using list view builder and i declare this if condition out side the list view builder and it solve my issue
`bool hasUid = false;
    for (var data in mobileDbList) {
      if (data["userid"] == uid) {
        hasUid = true;
        break;
      }
    }`

Comment: Good to hear you got it working!  --- Consider posting your full solution as an answer below, so that others can benefit from your experience going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix my problem using list view builder and i declare this if condition out side the list view builder and it solve my issue

```
import 'package:bidding/global/global_variable.dart';
import 'package:bidding/screen/productDetail/product_detail.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AdList extends StatefulWidget {
  final DatabaseReference dbRef;
  final String? categoty;
  const AdList({super.key, required this.dbRef, required this.categoty});

  @override
  State<AdList> createState() => _AdListState();
}

class _AdListState extends State<AdList> {
  Map? valueDbMap;
  List valueDbList = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.dbRef.once().then((DatabaseEvent event) {
      if (event.snapshot.value != null) {
        valueDbMap = event.snapshot.value as Map;
        valueDbMap![Key] = event.snapshot.key;
        valueDbMap!.forEach((key, value) {
               valueDbList.add(value);
        });

        setState(() {});
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool hasUid = false;
    for (var data in valueDbList) {
      if (data["userid"] == uid) {
        hasUid = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    return Container(
      child: valueDbList.isNotEmpty
          ? hasUid
              ? SizedBox(
                  height: 200, // Set a fixed height for the row
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection:
                        Axis.horizontal, // Set scroll direction to horizontal
                    itemCount:  valueDbList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      if(valueDbList[index]["userid"] == uid){
                        return  Text("Your id exist");
                      } else{
                        return SizedBox.shrink();
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                )
              : Text(
                  "Your id does not exist",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    color: cRed,
                  ),
                )
          : const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```